# How to generate and download multiple files at once with javascript (jsPdf) and firefox?

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, download, jspdf

I'm using JsPDF to generate a number of PDF files and then download them. With Chrome and Edge it's correctly generating and downloading all of them, but with Firefox is downloading only the first one.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        let doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'hello');
        for(a = 0; a < 6; a++){
            // doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');  < NOT WORKING ON RECENT BROWERS.
            // doc.output('datauri');
            // doc.addHTML($('#content'), 1, 1, function () {
            //     var blob = doc.output("blob");
            //     window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            // });

            doc.save('file_number_' + 'a' + '.pdf'); < DOWNLOADS ONLY THE FIRST FILE IN FIREFOX.
        }
    });
</script>
```

How could I be able to download all the generated files? It would be OK even if I could open them in a new window, as long as I'm able to specify the filename of the PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: as indicated by pytness, it appears Firefox is blocking the process.
I just tried to delay the clicks in this way:

```
function clickAll(){
            let waiter = 0;
            $('.pdf_line').each( 
                function(){
                    if ($(this).find('input').prop('checked')){
                        //console.log('click! waiter = ' + waiter);
                        $(this).find('.print_document').delay(4000*waiter).click(); 
                        waiter++;
                    };
                }
            )
        }
```

But after the first download Firefox halts the whole process.

Comment: Are you sure the browser is not blocking downloads? Browsers usually block multiple javascript fired downloads to prevent downloads not authorized by the user

Comment: That's what i'm afraid of. I just updated the main question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re saving the file with the same name every time in your loop, so it’s just saving over it each time.  Try changing the ‘a’ in your doc.save to a

Comment: As a side note. We’re you able to download more than 10 at a time in chrome? Mine stops at 10 files using chrome.

Comment: Thanks Jared! unfortunately, even cycling the name it doesn't work.